# Where should I change the window size in c# WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF window.
its xaml file is built of a UserControl tag:

```
<UserControl x:Class="DeploymentTool.View.ToolPanelMappingView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
         ...
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="1300"
         >
```

Apparently it doesn't matter what I change the width size to (1300 in my case),
it doesn't change the window size.

How can I change my window's width?

Comment: Your control probably has a `<Window>` tag in it's beginning. Just find it and you can change it's size.

Comment: No, it doesn't have a <window> tag. It has a <Grid> tag, but doesn't have a width attribute...

Comment: Look at it this way, no `Window` tag - no window. You do have one in your app, just look for it in the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your control is hosted inside another window.
Find the hosting window and change it as you wish.

Maybe you can try Snoop to fin the parent windwo and play with its properties to get the layput you want.
[Snoop on CodePlex](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Happens all of the time... I highly recommend that you use **Snoop** or some alternative, it helps a lot in finding problems like this one.  Happy new year!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your xaml probably is like this:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.SomeWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="SomeWindow" Height="700" Width="1300">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <UserControl            
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
     xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
     xmlns:telerik="http://schemas.telerik.com/2008/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"         
     mc:Ignorable="d" 
     d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="30" Background="Green" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"></UserControl>

</Grid>
```

So to change width and height of UserControl, you can do it by adding rows or columns in the 'Grid'.